# Python: logging object loses its file handler when passed to an RQ task queue

Tags: python, python-rq

## Problem

I pass a `logging` (`logger`) object, supposed to add lines to `test.log`, to a function `background_task()` that is run by the `rq` utility (task queues manager). `logger` has a `FileHandler` assigned to it to allow logging to `test.log`. Until `background_task()` is run, you can see the file handler present in `logger.handlers`, but when the `logger` is passed to `background_task()` and `background_task()` is run by `rq worker`, `logger.handlers` gets empty.

But if I ditch `rq` (and `Redis`) and just run `background_task` right away, the content of `logger.handlers` is preserved. So, it has something to do with `rq` (and, probably, task queuing in general, it's a new topic for me).

## Steps to reproduce

1. Run `add_job.py`: `python3 add_job.py`. You'll see the output of `print(logger.handlers)` called from within `add_job()`: there will be a handlers list containing `FileHandler` added in `get_job_logger()`.
2. Run command `rq worker` to start executing the queued task. You'll see the output of `print(logger.handlers)` once again but this time called from within `background_task()` and the list will be empty! Handlers of the `logging` (`logger`) object somehow get lost when the function that accepts a logger as an argument is run by `rq` (`rq worker`). What gives?

Here's how it looks like in the terminal:

```
$ python3 add_job.py
[<FileHandler /home/user/project/test.log (INFO)>]

$ rq worker
17:44:45 Worker rq:worker:2bbad3623e95438f81396c662cb01284: started, version 1.10.1
17:44:45 Subscribing to channel rq:pubsub:2bbad3623e95438f81396c662cb01284
17:44:45 *** Listening on default...
17:44:45 default: tasks.background_task(<RootLogger root (INFO)>) (5a5301be-efc3-49a7-ab0c-f7cf0a4bd3e5)
[]
```

## Source code

add_job.py

```
import logging
from logging import FileHandler
from redis import Redis
from rq import Queue

from tasks import background_task


def add_job():
    r = Redis()
    qu = Queue(connection=r)
    logger = get_job_logger()

    print(logger.handlers)

    job = qu.enqueue(background_task, logger)


def get_job_logger():
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    logger_file_handler = FileHandler('test.log')
    logger_file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logger.addHandler(logger_file_handler)

    return logger


if __name__ == '__main__':
    add_job()
```

tasks.py

```
def background_task(logger):
    print(logger.handlers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/t1e2n0/python_logging_object_loses_its_file_handler_when/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

> FileHandler does not get carried over into other threads. You start the FileHandler in the main thread and rq worker starts other threads. Memory is not shared like that.

> Hm, I see... Thanks!
>
> I assumed the FileHandler was being serialized or whatnot when written to Redis as a part of the whole logger object and then reinitialized when popping out of the queue.
>
> Anyway, I'll try passing a file path to the function and initialize a logger from within. That way, keeping the FileHandler object to one thread.
>
> EDIT: yeah, it works